# How to attach VSCode C++ Windows debugger to an embarcadero project process?

Tags: c++, delphi, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am working on a legacy project written in Embarcadero using Delphi and C++. I am trying to configure VSCode for it to an extent. I am currently stuck on configuring the debugger. Whenever I try to debug it every breakpoint says "No symbols have been loaded for this document.". Yes, my symbolSearchPath is not set but looking through the project settings the paths to symbol files are empty even though I can debug perfectly on RAD Studio. Is there even a way to attach VSCode debugging to a project like this? If so, is it because of the debugging symbols or because of something else? And how do I find the path to them?

Comment: The symbols produced by RAD Studio are not compatible with the format used by Visual Studio's debugger. And the Delphi symbols are not usable by any other debugger than the one in RAD Studio - they're language specific to Delphi.

Comment: I am actually looking into this: https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb as RAD Studio documentation mentions the use of DWARF symbols in their debugger. However I haven't had any luck running it yet